# Is it possible to create an open group for a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

This group should be an integrated part of the Facebook Page (cf. Page Events) and be represented as a tab in the tab menu.

Does Facebook provide such a feature for Facebook pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not possible. There is no such feature available. There is [difference between Facebook pages and groups](https://www.facebook.com/help/155275634539412).